# Oracle invalid identifier GroupBy

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run this oracle query. The error I get is `"EMAIL": invalid identifier` I don't know why? If I remove `EMAIL` then the error `"SHARES": invalid identifier`. It says that for every  item in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT IssueId, AcctNbr, NAME, rtrim(ADDRES) AS ADDRESS1, CITY, STATE, ZIP , 
  CASE 
    WHEN hocnty = 0 THEN 'UNITED STATES' 
    WHEN hocnty > 0 THEN (SELECT cnname from money.country WHERE cnint = hocnty)
  END AS COUNTRY, 
  (Shares + pplnsh) AS SHARES, 
  adadr2 AS EMAIL
FROM money.holder, money.pos, money.address
WHERE issueid = adiss AND holderid = adhold AND adend = 0 AND adpurp in (20, 21, 22) AND issueid = 1 AND POSITION_CLOSE_DATE is Null 
GROUP BY IssueId, AcctNbr, NAME, ADDRESS1, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRY, SHARES, EMAIL 
ORDER BY name ASC, shares DESC
```

Comment: You are trying to group by the aliases of your columns, try either using the same expression or use a derived table instead

Comment: I get `ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here` when i try to put the case in the group by

Comment: Then use your current select as a derived table

Comment: Im sorry I dont know what you mean by that, im new to oracle.

Comment: You use your current query (without the GROUP BY and ORDER BY) as your derived table: `SELECT ... FROM (<current query here without group by>) as T GROUP BY .... ORDER BY ....`